# uSD-card PCB front edge smoothing

Tags: pcb-fabrication, sd, mechanical

Looking for the appropriate (best) technology to smooth or coat the PCB surface to minimize uSD-card connector pint wear-out.

Here's the layout

[image]

The uSD-card specification is

[image]

uSD cards, to my understanding, are having either plastic case or coated surface, and they can achieve least contact-to-front-bevel-edge friction when inserted and removed. If I manufacture PCB with such a bevel edge, PCB will have FR4 material exposed, to my experience it is very harsh, and the bevel edged space on the PCB will act as a sandpaper for the uSD-card contacts.

Is there any technology, either for the PCB fabrication or the one applied manually after fabrication, which would reliably prevent harsh PCB surface scratching the connector pins? Coat front of PCB with lacquer? Put solder mask onto it in production?

Comment: I just looked at a couple of micro-SD cards, and the bevels were very small indeed; I was wondering how bad the effects sould be with no bevel it at all?

Comment: @jonathanjo no bevel is also an option: https://wiki.tizen.org/SDWire and https://docs.dasharo.com/transparent-validation/sd-wire/getting-started/ and https://www.tindie.com/products/stefan321/sdwire-pcb/ but how good this option is?